# Search whole word for 3 periods. Trying to find linked server usage in procs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to find all references to linked servers in procs.
I tried [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/t-sql-query-to-find-the-list-of-objects-referring-linked-servers) but it returns a lot of procs that do not have any linked servers in them at all.

With that said, I wanted to use either `PATINDEX` or `LIKE` to look for the 4 parts strings which will most likely be the linked servers.

4 part name being `[server].[database].[schema].[object]`

I tried something like this.

```sql
-- this does not work
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS SchemaName,
    OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS ProcedureName,
    m.definition AS ProcedureDefinition
FROM
    sys.procedures AS p
    JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m ON p.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE
    PATINDEX('%[^.][.][^.][.][^.][.][^.]%', m.definition) > 0
    OR PATINDEX('%[^.][.][^.][.][.][^.]%', m.definition) > 0
ORDER BY
    SchemaName,
    ProcedureName;


-- works BUT SEE BELOW
select 1 where upper('1.2.3.4') LIKE '%[A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9]%'

-- does not work because there is more than one character
select 1 where upper('1.22.3.4') LIKE '%[A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9]%'

-- works BUT SEE BELOW
select 1 where upper('1.22.3.4') LIKE '%[A-Z0-9][.]%[A-Z0-9][.]%[A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9]%'

-- this also works but I want it to fail since it has spaces in it.
select 1 where upper('1.2 2.3.4') LIKE '%[A-Z0-9][.]%[A-Z0-9][.]%[A-Z0-9][.][A-Z0-9]%'

-- works BUT SEE BELOW
select 1 where upper('1.2 2.3.4') LIKE '%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.]%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.]%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.][\[A-Z0-9\]]%' ESCAPE '\'

-- this works but I want it to fail since it has spaces outside the square brackets
select 1 where upper('1. [2 2].3.4') LIKE '%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.]%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.]%[\[A-Z0-9\]][.][\[A-Z0-9\]]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The last piece of the 4 part name can get tricky with the periods because in SQL Server the following is valid.
`[server].[database]..[object]`
NOTICE the "empty" schema? This is assumed to be DBO schema if not given.
So the LIKE clause needs to account for 2 periods together.
For that part I could do an OR with LIKE again where it has 2 periods together.
I did try a lot of REGEX inside `PATINDEX` but nothing worth posting.

I can't seem to find a good way to check an entire word for 3 periods without spaces in it.
I also need to use the square brackets "[" and "]" since that could be around each section of a 4 part SQL name.
I am using `LIKE '%\[%\]%' ESCAPE '\'` to detect the square brackets.

Does anyone know some what in SQL Server to search a "whole word" and not include spaces?

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to do. What's wrong with `select object_name(referencing_id), * from sys.sql_expression_dependencies where referenced_server_name is not null`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for that code. I was not aware of the dependencies checker. If you want to post this as the answer, I will accept it so you get the points.